# Select minimum column not equal to zero

Tags: mysql

We have 2 columns in a table and want to SELECT the lesser most of the two (unless it is equal to 0, then we want the nonzero column).

Is there a way to do this while keeping it a simple SELECT statement?

What we want is this:
`SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) FROM myTable`
Unless col2 is 0, in which case we want col1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(
         IF(col1, col1, col2),
         IF(col2, col2, col1)
       )
FROM   myTable
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, can you point me to some doc for the IF(x, y, z) syntax?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if: "*If `expr1` is `TRUE` (`expr1 <> 0` and `expr1 <> NULL`) then `IF()` returns `expr2`; otherwise it returns `expr3`.*"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN col1 = 0 THEN col2
        WHEN col2 = 0 THEN col1
        ELSE LEAST(col1, col2)
    END AS MinCol
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This worked as well with some minor tweaking. I didn't know MySQL had this control structure really neat!